# Como puedo quitar los SLASHES al consultar json e insertar en otra tabla

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Tengo un problema con mi código de php
quiero consultar un json e insertarlo en una tabla de los historiales el problema es que quiero guardar array que está dentro de mi json pero me lo aguarda con el slashes `"[{\"idFile\": \"10\"}]"` y requiero que este sin los SLASHES `[{"idFile": "10"}]`

Lo que hago es esto:

```
INSERT INTO `historial_dibujos`( `IdMod`, `NoDibujo`, `DibFiles`, `DibDesc`, `DibFechaR`, `DibStatus`)
 SELECT 6330,
      REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(ModDataDibujo, '$.NoDibujo'), '\"',''),
```

En esta parte hago que elimine las comillas y los slashes, funciona correctamente en phpmyadmin pero ya en el codigo php me truena

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(ModDataDibujo, '$.DibFiles'), '\\',''), '\"[', '['),']\"', ']'),
```

a si que intente hacer esto otro:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(ModDataDibujo, '$.DibFiles'), '\\\"','\"'), '\"[', '['),']\"', ']'),
```

aquí me funciona correctamente pero no me da el resultado deseado si no que me da `[{\"idFile\": \"10\"}]`

```
      REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(ModDataDibujo, '$.DibDesc'), '\"',''),
      REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(ModDataDibujo, '$.DibFechaR'), '\"',''),
      REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(ModDataDibujo, '$.DibStatus'), '\"','') 
 FROM modelos2 AS m WHERE m.IdMod = 6330
```

Versión de PHP: 7.4.27

Versión del servidor: 10.4.22-MariaDB

Comment: De primeras el array que estas intentando guardar no tiene un formato adecuado, pero no lo digo por los backslashes, esos estan bien, lo digo porque eso que tienes ahi no es un arreglo ni tampoco un objeto, es decir, si es un array, pero lo que tienes dentro de el es un error de sintaxis.

Comment: hola mmm... no comprendo... aque te refieres?

Comment: Me refiero a que `"[\"idFile\": \"10\"]"`, no es un array con formato valido, eso que indicas seria valido si fuese un objeto: `"{\"idFile\": \"10\"}"`

Comment: tienes toda la razón permíteme corregirlo la pregunta gracias no me había percatado de la falta de corchetes...

Comment: Los slashes son para escapar las comillas. Revisa bien cómo estás operando con los JSON...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo que sigas guardando los `JSON` con esos slashes, porque a fin de cuentas, estos caracteres permiten que el formato JSON pueda ser guardado en casi cualquier base de datos, ademas, al ser parseado ten en cuenta que la mayoria de veces, tanto en javascript como en `PHP`, cuando parseas un `JSON` se quitan automaticamente esos slash.

Entonces, si necesitas usar esa información que te trae desde la base de datos desde `PHP` puedes usar `json_decode`:

```
$informacion = "[{\"idFile\": \"10\"}]";

$info_parseada = json_decode($informacion);//Array[Class { idFile }]

print_r($info_parseada[0]);                //Class { idFile }
print_r($info_parseada[0]->idFile);        //int 10
```

Y si es por parte de javascript tenemos nativamente funciones para ello, como por ejemplo el metodo `parse` del objeto `JSON`:

```js
const informacion = "[{\"idFile\": \"10\"}]";
const info_parseada = JSON.parse(informacion);

console.log(info_parseada);
console.log(info_parseada[0]);
console.log(info_parseada[0].idFile);
```

Comment: Ah, y por supuesto ya no te harian falta esas extrañas operaciones de conversion para quitar esos slashes en tus consultas de la BD, ya que a fin de cuentas, el cliente o el servidor, como vimos va a poder usarlas sin esos backslashes, a pesar de que en la base de datos existan.

Comment: en parte tienes razón, aunque realmente mi pregunta pues era más si existía otra manera de guardarlo o me estaba equivocando en algo, pues mi intención era más hacerlo todo desde el servidor, guardarlo correctamente y ya solo hacer la consulta sin hacer más pasos extra...

Comment: bueno también se puede hacer  ```$informacion = "[{\"idFile\": \"10\"}]";
$info_parseada = json_decode(json_decode($informacion));``` y tambien funciona ademas asi te evitas hacerlo en  javascript :D

Comment: @handerGarcía si, aunque yo la verdad recomendaba dejarlo con los slashes debido a que en mi caso, y la verdad no se porque,  el mismo engine me los guardaba asi, sin embargo, cuando trataba de almacenar esa misma información pero sin los slashes me daba error, por eso recomiendo dejarlos, porque de todas maneras esos slashes no afectan en nada al final.